# How does the Chinese character  pronounce in Hanyu Pinyin?

Tags: pronunciation

I want to how the rare Chinese character  pronounce. After [looking up](https://www.biquku.com/search/sozi.php?zi=%F0%A4%87%BC) [several](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%F0%A4%87%BC) [dictionaries](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/z44679f.html), the first source said the character had entered wrongly, the second and third source did not provide any hanyu pinyin pronunciation. When I attempted to pronounce it via Bing Translate, it pronouces "暂不支持这个字的发音", so the translator does not support pronunciation of this character. Furthermore, I couldn't find this character in any book dictionaries (such as 现代汉语词典). This character is useful when mentioning people (for exmaple in Ming Shilu/明实录), but none of the dictionaries said how to pronounce this character. So, how to pronounce this character? I think it pronounces "ān" in Hanyu Pinyin. Thank you to answer this question.

(Note: The character pronunciation question for the first character  recalled due to out of scope, as it is a Vietnamese-Zhuang-only character. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zisea |](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=241FC)

> 粤语ngon1、on1
> 人名用字。见《明实录》

Seems to be a Cantonese character read ngon1 or, more lazily, on1.

Its most likely Mandarin reading would therefore be an1. But, it doesn't seem to have any place in MSM.